# Go race detection for buildmode c-shared or c-archive

Tags: go

It it possible to enable the Go race detector for Go code linked into a C++ application? The Go library is built with the -race option and it is linked into a C++ application that interacts with it using CGo. Passing GORACE environment options does not seem to trigger the tool, for example,

> gdb --args env GORACE="halt_on_error=1" ...

The program can't be started using

> go run -race ..

because it isn't a Go binary.

Comment: One approach has been to extract the Go library from the application, connect it to the application using sockets, then build the Go library as a binary and run it stand-alone. This is a different test than I'd like to run but it does make race available - where it happens to find no issues.